# Asserting a specific stub call was made with the required arguments using sinon

Tags: unit-testing, qunit, sinon

Let's say you are testing a function that will call a dependency multiple times with different arguments:

```
var sut = {
    ImportantFunction: function(dependency){
        dependency("a", 1);
        dependency("b", 2);
    }
};
```

Using QUnit + Sinon **and assuming the order of the calls is not important**, I could write the following test that makes sure the function calls the dependency as expected:

```
test("dependency was called as expected", function () {
    var dependencyStub = sinon.stub();

    sut.ImportantFunction(dependencyStub);

    ok(dependencyStub.calledTwice, "dependency was called twice");            
    sinon.assert.calledWith(dependencyStub, "a", 1);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(dependencyStub, "b", 2);
});
```

**But what if the order is important and I want the test to take it into account?** What is the best way to write such a test using QUnit+Sinon?

I have used the following approach, but I am losing the descriptive failure message provided by [sinon assertions](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#assertions) (which shows expected and actual values). For this I have just manually added some descriptive message, but it is not as useful as having a failure message with the expected and actual values (and has to be manually maintained).

```
ok(dependencyStub.firstCall.calledWith("a", 1), "dependency called with expected args 'a', 1");
ok(dependencyStub.secondCall.calledWith("b", 2), "dependency called with expected args 'b', 2");
```

Is there a way of using an assertion like `sinon.assert.calledWith` for a particular call like the first or second call?

Sample setup in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bu0u1exs/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sinon.assert.callOrder(spy1, spy2, ...)`, or `spy1.calledBefore(spy2)` or `spy2.calledAfter(spy1)`.

These can also be used with the result of `spy.calledWith(...)`, e.g. `sinon.assert.callOrder(spy.withArgs('a'), spy.withArgs('b'))`.

Comment: Thanks, this allows nice tests too and works in older versions of Sinon :)

Answer (score 10):

And just as I was creating the sample fiddle I have found the solution...

In my code I was using version 1.7.1 of Sinon, but while writing the fiddle using Sinon's latest version (1.14.1 as of today) I just realized that you can pass a particular spyCall to the `assert.calledWith` method. This means you can write the following:

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(dependencyStub.firstCall, "a", 1);
sinon.assert.calledWith(dependencyStub.secondCall, "b", 2);
```

So the test I wanted to create can be nicely written:

```
test("dependency was called multiple times as expected - with order", function () {
    var dependencyStub = sinon.stub();

    sut.ImportantFunction(dependencyStub);

    sinon.assert.calledTwice(dependencyStub);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(dependencyStub.firstCall, "a", 1);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(dependencyStub.secondCall, "b", 2);    
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xq1fw2tt/2/)

**Edit**

Found in the github repository [the discussion](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/580) that introduced this change. **By the date the change was merged to master, this should work on version 1.13.0 and newer.**

If you are using older versions, you can use mantoni´s solution:

```
test("dependency was called multiple times as expected with order - pre 1.13.0", function () {
    var dependencyStub = sinon.stub();

    sut.ImportantFunction(dependencyStub);

    sinon.assert.calledTwice(dependencyStub);
    sinon.assert.callOrder(
        dependencyStub.withArgs("a", 1), 
        dependencyStub.withArgs("b", 2));
});
```