# Sinon.js combining calledWith number of times

Tags: unit-testing, sinon

I know with [sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org) you can test that a spy was called a certain number of times:

```
sinon.assert.calledTwice(mySpy.someMethod);
```

And you can test that a spy was called with certain arguments:

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(mySpy.someMethod, 1, 2);
```

But how to you combine them to test that a method was called a specific number of times with specific arguments? Something, theoretically, like this:

```
sinon.assert.calledTwiceWith(mySpy.someMethod, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29899656/12484

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `spy` provides access to the calls made to it using [`getCall()` and `getCalls()`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/spies/#var-spycall--spygetcalln).  Each [Spy call](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/spy-call/) can be tested using methods like [`calledWithExactly()`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/spy-call/#spycallcalledwithexactlyarg1-arg2-):

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

test('spy', () => {

  const spy = sinon.spy();
  spy(1, 2);
  spy(3, 4);
  expect(spy.callCount).toBe(2);
  expect(spy.getCall(0).calledWithExactly(1, 2)).toBe(true);
  expect(spy.getCall(1).calledWithExactly(3, 4)).toBe(true);

});
```

Comment: This will not work if you don't know the order that the calls are going to be made in.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Sinon doesn't have a function that checks what you're looking for, especially if you don't know or care about the order of calls ahead of time. However, it does let you inspect each time that a function was called individually. As a result, although it's a bit inelegant, you can count the number of times the function was called with the expected arguments yourself.

Use `spy.getCalls()` to get an array of the spy's calls, which are instances of [spy call objects](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v13/spy-call/). Each call lets you access an array of the arguments passed to the spy with `call.args` (not `call.args()`).

```js
test('spy', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy();
  spy(1, 2);
  spy(1, 2);
  spy(3, 4);

  const wantedCalls = spy.getCalls().filter(
    (call) => call.args.length === 2 && call.args[0] === 1 && call.args[1] === 2
  );

  expect(wantedCalls.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

A bit more cleanly, as [Brian Adams points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52088572), you can call `call.calledWithExactly()` to check the arguments a specific call received:

```js
test('spy', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy();
  spy(1, 2);
  spy(1, 2);
  spy(3, 4);

  const wantedCalls = spy.getCalls().filter(
    (call) => call.calledWithExactly(1, 2)
  );

  expect(wantedCalls.length).toEqual(2);
});
```